# Conditionally constexpr expressions with if constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose you have a function template that calls another function, which may or may not be a `constexpr` function depending on a template parameter.  C++ allows the callee to be declared `constexpr` anyway, as long as at least one possible instantiation produces a `constexpr`.

For example:

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool bar() { return true; }

template <>
bool bar<int>() { return false; }

template <class T>
constexpr bool foo() { return bar<T>(); }

foo<short>();
foo<int>(); // not a constexpr, but compiles anyway
```

This allows a nice degree of flexibility so that we can produce `constexpr` function calls whenever possible, but fall back to a non-constexpr otherwise.

However, I notice the same flexibility does not extend to the C++17 `if constexpr`.

For example:

```
if constexpr(foo<short>()) { /* do something */ }; // works
if constexpr(foo<int>()) { /* do something */ }; // won't compile, bar<int>() is not constexpr!
```

I've encountered situations where I'd like to use `if constexpr` to avoid the compilation time overhead of instantiating certain templates, but the evaluated expression may not always be a `constexpr` depending on template parameters.  Is there some reason that `if constexpr` doesn't just "degrade" to a non-constexpr `if` statement if the conditional expression depends on a template parameter and the template instantiates to a non-constexpr?  Just like with the behavior of `constexpr` functions?

Is this simply an arbitrary omission in the standard (i.e. nobody thought it would be useful), or is there some more fundamental reason why `if constexpr` can't "degrade" to a non-constexpr `if`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't "degrade" for the same reason that this doesn't degrade:

```
constexpr auto value = expression;
```

If you declare a variable to be `constexpr`, then you *mean it*. You mean that its value is a compile-time constant, and the compiler will perform constant evaluation to generate its value.

The same goes for `if constexpr`; the condition *is* a constant expression. `if constexpr` exists to choose between different pieces of code based on whether a particular constant expression yields certain values. It has special discarding mechanics that allow ill-formed code to exist in conditions not taken under certain circumstances.

There is no "degrading" here because there's not *supposed* to be. The question really is not why `if constexpr` can't "degrade"; it's why function `constexpr` *does* "degrade". It's function-level `constexpr` that's the odd one out, and that oddity is why we had to [invent a whole new keyword in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) to mean "yes, I really definitely mean that this function is a constant expression".

Comment: Totally agree.  I've always found the "fallback" mechanics to be troublesome.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't necessarily agree with that. I don't think it would be useful for `if constexpr`, but it's very useful for function `constexpr`. The problem is not that we have a mechanism with fallbacks; it's that both the "degrading" and non-degrading version are *spelled the same way* (except for when they aren't thanks to `consteval`).

Comment: Agreed, the issue is just the syntax really. The semantics of both constructs is useful on their own.

Comment: In C++17 lambdas are implicitly `constexpr` if the rules allow. Why does this not work for functions? Why was this keyword introduced for functions at all? (Should I rather ask this as a question?)

Comment: @Dr.Gut: "*Why does this not work for functions?*" Define "work". How well does it "work" for lambdas? It certainly doesn't give me a compile error if I do something that isn't permitted in `constexpr` code; it just makes my lambda not implicitly `constexpr`. How do I tell the compiler that I *mean* for my code to be able to run at compile-time? The lambda implicit rule is a function of not having a place syntactically to put it, as well as wanting to keep C++'s lambda syntax from being even more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword `constexpr` means very different things in these 2 contexts:

```
constexpr void f();
```

and

```
if constexpr(expr)
```

In the case of `f`, the `constexpr` means that `f` *may be* evaluated at compile time. But it's perfectly fine to call `f` at run-time as well.

In the case of the `if constexpr`, the expression `expr` *must be* an expression that can be evaluated at compile time.

So in the case of the function `f`, it makes sense to "degrade" the constexpr-ness so that the function can be called at run-time, but this doesn't make sense in the context of the `constexpr if`.

I suggest thinking of these 2 forms as unrelated to each other (think of the `constexpr` keyword occuring in both cases as being a coincidence). If you are aware of the `consteval` keyword, then you can think of `if constexpr` as really being `if consteval` since the expression *must be* evaluated at compile time, similar to a `consteval` function.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that... I'm asking why exactly that is.  Why can't `if constexpr` simply "degrade" to a regular if statement if `expr` can't be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: @Siler It's just not designed to do that. I can't think of a reason off the top of my head that disallows such a construct. Not sure how it would be used though. What happens to the discarded branch if it degrades to a run-time check?

Answer (score 0):

If both branches of an `if` compile, you can use just a regular `if`.  If the compiler can prove that the condition always (or never) holds, it can **elide** one branch (although it still must instantiate everything needed for the other).  This can include non-constant expressions, like `i>1 || i<2`, but might or might not include any given constant expression because the compiler isn’t required to fully expand everything so as to check (and optimization is optional anyway).

In the unlikely event that somehow you know that the wrong branch will compile except perhaps in a subset of the circumstances in which the condition will be a constant expression (with the correct value!), you can use SFINAE to **detect** that:

```
template<class T,class=int[void(T::maybe()),1]>
constexpr bool use_maybe(int) {return true;}
template<class> constexpr bool use_maybe(long) {return false;}

template<class T> void client() {
  if(T::maybe()<4) {  // non-constant values are bigger
    if constexpr(use_maybe<T>(1)) {
      int buf[T::maybe()];
      T::use(buf);
    } else std::abort();
  } else {
    std::vector<int> buf(T::maybe());
    T::use(buf.data());
  }
}
```